# What is the FPS speed that the animation timeline runs at by default? Blender 2.9

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline, dopesheet, frame-rate

I'm currently learning to animate 3D to export for videogames but I'm having trouble with identifying the FPS speed.

When I press PLAY, at which speed does the animation play in the timeline? Is there any way to customize it? I don't really want it to be in 24FPS if I want to export it at 60FPS or whatever speed suits the project.

I've looked in the timeline, dopesheet, render tab and can't find anything regarding the timeline's FPS

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's in the render output settings. You can also change the start/end point, the step interval and even re-map the time if you like:

[image: FrameSpeed]